# Сказуемое в предложении

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор

**По возвращении домой Пьеру казалось, что он приехал из какого-то дальнего путешествия, где провел десятки лет.**

Во втором придаточном предложении сказуемым будет "провел десятки лет" или просто "провел"?

Answer (score 1):

Сказуемое в втором придаточном "провел". Это полнозначный глагол, а не вспомогательный.